# How to replace a certain word from a string with another one and excluding certain types of said word in atom regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, find, atom-editor

I'm using atom to try and find the word "Next" and replace it with the word "Continue", but only when the string starts with "al "" (the space and the quotation mark are important)

I've tried to use atom's Regex find and replace tool to accomplish this and I believe I'm quite close. The code below managed to find the strings I wanted, but I'm not sure how the replace code should go.

(al \")(.*Next)

I've tried fiddling with the $1 and $2 thingies, but I just can't seem to figure this out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should re-arrange the first capturing group bounds and remove the second one:

```
(al ".*)Next
```

Then, replace with `$1Continue`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ptTTnm/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(al%20%22.*)Next):

[image]

**Details**

- `(al ".*)` - Capturing group #1: `al`, space, `"` and then any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `Next` - a `Next` substring.

Note we capture what we need to keep and just match what we want to remove.